# Command not found after installing p7zip

Tags: command-line, 7zip

Just getting started with Linux/Ubuntu. I installed `7z` but the command is not found. I restarted the computer to hopefully refresh commands but that didn't help either.

Here is what I did:

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

Then tried

```
7z e [file-name].xz
```

and

```
7za e [file-name].xz
```

then I read up the `man` file but still nothing. Every time i get the following reply:

```
/usr/local/bin/7z: 2: /usr/local/bin/7z: /usr/local/lib/p7zip/7z: not found
```

Comment: I get the same error, except that I am trying to execute 7za instead of 7z. I have checked, and the files are located in the correct directories AFAIK. Do I need to reboot before these changes take effect?

Answer (score 5):

figured it out!

the path in the bin file was pointing to the wrong place.

i needed to switch the direction from the

```
usr/local/lib/p7zip/
```

directory to

```
usr/lib/p7zip/
```

directory....

Comment: Glad you solved the problem! What do you mean with “switched the direction”? Do you mean the shell script `/usr/bin/7z` contained `exec /usr/local/lib/p7zip/7z "$@"` instead of `exec /usr/lib/p7zip/7z "$@"`? If so, that’s a major issue justifying a [bug report](https://askubuntu.com/q/5121/507051) I think. I can’t confirm for the repo packages of 16.04 and 18.04 – what release do you use? Please add this information to your question ([edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1043159/edit)).

Comment: The real problem seems to be that you have a `7z` in `/usr/local/bin` that is unrelated to the packages that you installed via `apt`, but is being run preferentially because of the order of your `PATH`

Comment: I seem to have many 7z's around the computer, one on local and then a general one.  I am not exactly sure how the installation system works if I install a program with sudo apt-get and if it depends where I currently am in the file structure... I originally downloaded it from the sourceforge sight, then after that didnt work I used apt-get.

Comment: I would appreciate it if either of you could point me in the direction of a book or source of reading where I can better understand how to navigate through local vs home vs usr when installing files and where the bash files end up (or is that dictated by the installation file and not where I am? )  again - thanks for the help!

Comment: @dessert - the version that I downloaded from source forge was 16.02 but with the apt-get I am not sure (and actually am not sure how to find the version) doing 7z --version isnt working..

Answer (score 2):

`p7zip` isn't enough, also had to install `p7zip-plugins` ... then it's `/bin/7z`.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

[Thanks Amadeobee!](https://askubuntu.com/a/1043174/618353) `/usr/lib/p7zip/7z x your_file_name` can fix the issue.

Or you can edit `usr/local/bin/7z`:

```
sudo vim /usr/local/bin/7z
```

replacing:

```
/usr/local/lib/p7zip/7z
```

with:

```
/usr/lib/p7zip/7z
```

The result is as follows:

```
(base) j@lab:~/doc/code$ 7z x deep_motion_mag-master.7z
/usr/local/bin/7z: 2: /usr/local/bin/7z: /usr/local/lib/p7zip/7z: not found
(base) j@lab:~/doc/code$ 7z x deep.7z
7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,32 CPUs)
Processing archive: deep_motion_mag-master.7z
Extracting  deep
Extracting  deep/configs
...
```